# HTML5 video how do I show last video frame when seeking to end?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

When I manually call:

```
player.currentTime = player.duration
```

(1) The video `currentTime` jumps to the end (desired and expected)

(2) The video starts playback from the start when I click play (desired and expected)

(3) The video does not update to show the last frame (undesired and unexpected)

Currently, I am having to do this:

```
player.currentTime = player.duration - 0.0001
player.play()
```

Which causes the video to jump close to the end and then resumes playback and then almost immediately stops when it hits the end, which fixes my problem in that the video now shows the last frame.

However, this feels somewhat hacky and cannot be as fast as simply just setting the current time. Is there a better fix? thanks

NOTE: the seek to end operation must support code programmatic code execution (e.g. code execution in response to a button click). I am NOT using the players built in seek/scrub bar (which works fine).

Comment: Are you saying you see blank/black frame at end ? if so I think its problem with video itself. In [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) example I don't see blank at end.

Comment: I am not using the players built in scrub / seek bar (which works fine) ... I am coding a button that when clicked jumps the video to the end

Comment: The last frame in the video is NOT blank, when I use the native scrub bar OR when the video just plays to the end, the last frame shows fine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xjnao5gw/ - Jumps to the last frame, without an additional `.play()` or `.pause()`

Comment: I tested `player.currentTime = player.duration`, and it jumps to last frame. seems its problem with video or something else/

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for taking time to code this ... but in your example, the video is not at the end ... if you click play on the video controls it resumes playback but then stops again ... however, I acknowledge my issue is not present

Comment: thanks @bogdanoff for your help - see comment immediately above, which shows that  player.currentTime = player.duration does not seek to end - however, it does appear to be a different problem which suggests my problem is a problem with my setup given your results - thanks - I'll look into it - feel free to provide an answer and I will accept

Comment: @danday74 I think I found answer,  in firefox setting `player.currentTime = player.duration` triggers  "ended" event, thus video ends (no gap at end of seek bar).
But in chrome is this different, in chrome setting currentTime wont invoke "ended" event and there is slight gap end of seek bar (i think this is what you were referring)
here link to my  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuqm2v47/1/)

Comment: thanks please add this as answer, yes your jsfiddle mirrors the behaviour @Andreas mentioned, much appreciated, your investigation work very helpful - clearly a Chrome issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found answer, in firefox setting
`player.currentTime = player.duration`
triggers "ended" event, thus video ends (no gap at end of seek bar).

But in chrome is this different, in chrome setting `player.currentTime = player.duration` won't trigger "ended" event and there is slight gap end of seek bar (i think this is what you were referring).
Link to my test [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuqm2v47/1/).

*TL:DR The good old vendor issue*

Also setting `player.currentTime = player.duration + 99999` in chrome doesn't trigger "ended" event and seek bar still has gap at end.

So current work around for this bug is

```js
stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  player.currentTime = player.duration
  player.play() // trick for chrome
})

// to verify
player.addEventListener('ended', (e) => console.log(e.target.ended ? "ended" : "not ended"))
```

This code works on both firefox and chrome and results are exact same.